# What action is invoked when today widget center is being closed?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, today-extension, osx-today-widget

I need to find the way to respond to notification centre being closed/hidden. The reason is that I have a pop up `NSMenu` in that widget, and if you open it and then close entire notification centre, pop up menu remains on the screen.

I have already tried to implement `NSWindowDelegate` but there is no such event that defines closing of today widget centre. The closest things I found are `-windowDidMiniaturize:` and 
`-windowWillClose:`. But when side bar closes they are not invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found needed method in `NSWindowDelegate` protocol.

First step is to add self (in that case it is `viewController`) as an observer for desired method: `windowDidResignKey:`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear {
  //set this view controller delegate for selector windowDidResignKey
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowDidResignKey:) name:NSWindowDidResignKeyNotification object:self.view.window];
}
```

And second is to implement this method:

```
- (void)windowDidResignKey:(NSNotification *)notification {
  //If window did resign key (close today center) - close menus
  if(_sourceLanguageMenu)
    [ _sourceLanguageMenu cancelTracking];
  if(_targetLanguageMenu)
    [ _targetLanguageMenu cancelTracking];
}
```